# python highest value in a csv data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I get a list from a dataframe, and the list goes

```
list = [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 4, 2, 6, 8]
```

I want to get returned a dataframe that plots the highest recognized value. ex:

```
list2= [1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8]
```

As shown in the example above, a new list is generated. plots the highest value found.

I need it returned as its own column in the dataframe file.
My code for referrence;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# read data frame
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
# numbers list: [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 4, 2, 6, 8]
df['numbers']

# here will go the code you guys give me ###
df['highestnumbers'] = #####################
```

the output should be a list that goes

```
[1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8]
```

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey the question is, how do I do what I explained I was trying to do.

Comment: @WockyBocky What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey Ive tried using the .max() function but it only returns a single value.

Comment: @WockyBocky Well one option would be to use the `max()` function in a loop, but if you think about it you can probably do it more efficiently. I would start with that though.

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey I did; df['highestnumbers'] = df['numbers'].max()     . This function only returns one value, I neeed it find the max of EACH cumulative value withtin the dataframe

Comment: @WockyBocky Try putting it in a loop, and each iteration you can make it calculate the max of one more element

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey thanks I figured it out, I combined the .max() with .expanding()   . I did df['highestnumbers'] = df['numbers'].expanding().max()

Comment: how do I upvote people, im new to this site

Comment: @WockyBocky Good work, since I didn't post an answer there is no need to upvote, what you can do is answer your own question and you will be able to mark it as the accepted answer in one day. This way your question will not be left as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

df['highestnumbers'] = df['numbers'].expanding().max()